# Write to Spreadsheet in Google sheet from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-sheets, google-api

I have a code, it should write in the Spreadsheet of google sheet. When I run the function, I receive this error:

> **Message[Requested writing within range ['6/12/2019-20:37'!A1], but**
>   **tried writing to column [B]] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest]**
>   **Domain[global]**

That its my code:

```
        private void SheetPattern(Item webinar)
    {
        var valueRange = new ValueRange();
        var range = $"{sheet}!A:D";

        DateTime dateTime=(DateTime)webinar.webInfo.times[0].startTime;
        var date = dateTime.Day+"-"+dateTime.Month+"-"+dateTime.Year;
        var hour = dateTime.Hour + ":" + dateTime.Minute;
        var webName = webinar.webInfo.subject;
        var webDescription = webinar.webInfo.description;

        var oblist = new List<object>() { date, hour, webName, webDescription};

        valueRange.Values = new List<IList<object>> { oblist };

        var appendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, SpreadsheetId, range);
        Console.WriteLine(appendRequest);
        appendRequest.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
        var appendReponse = appendRequest.Execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem its a Syntax problem, here:

```
var hour = dateTime.Hour + ":" + dateTime.Minute;
```

when I make a new sheet with a new name, google sheet doesn't permit the char `:` in the sheet name. So I change this code for that code:

```
var hour = dateTime.Hour + "-" + dateTime.Minute;
```